# Node 1 image (challenge from vulnhub) with an Ubuntu system has no ip address

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

Installed vbox on windows 10 with Node 1 security challenge (ubuntu) mounted from vulnhub, doesn't get IP address or it's not accessible. Host-only option doesn't show any address for this machine in`ipconfig` of a host machine. (Or any other). One of the overlaps on Node 1 vulnhub site shows that dhcp service is enabled and ip addresss is automatically assigned for this challenge. How to connect to this virtual machine (guest)? I tried disabling firewall but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how to get this information from vbox, but if you can determine the MAC address used by the VM, you can then use "arp -a" from a command line to determine the IP address assigned to that MAC address, and thus the VM. The VM should be running when you do this.